# Hibernate mostra ddl mas não cria as tabelas no banco

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Ao iniciar o wildfly eu esperava que as tabelas fossem criadas no banco porém no console mostra um log de create tables porém nada acontece no banco. Abaixo mostro isso:

```
    14:15:00,462 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
    14:15:00,880 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
    14:15:00,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
    14:15:03,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found pokemax.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called pokemax.war.dodeploy
    14:15:03,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
    14:15:03,171 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
    14:15:03,208 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
    14:15:03,333 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
    14:15:03,333 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
    14:15:03,348 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
    14:15:03,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
    14:15:03,401 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
    14:15:03,425 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
    14:15:03,427 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
    14:15:03,460 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
    14:15:03,487 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
    14:15:03,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
    14:15:03,722 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
    14:15:03,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
    14:15:03,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
    14:15:03,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
    14:15:03,797 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
    14:15:03,810 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
    14:15:04,221 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
    14:15:04,285 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
    14:15:04,324 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
    14:15:04,344 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
    14:15:04,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
    14:15:04,517 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
    14:15:04,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    14:15:05,197 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
    14:15:05,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "pokemax.war" (runtime-name: "pokemax.war")
    14:15:05,575 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
    14:15:05,594 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
    14:15:05,573 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
    14:15:05,571 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
    14:15:05,836 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
    14:15:09,089 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for pokemax
    14:15:09,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'pokemax.war#pokemax'
    14:15:09,469 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: pokemax
        ...]
    14:15:09,579 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment pokemax.war
    14:15:09,707 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
    14:15:09,712 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    14:15:09,722 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    14:15:09,843 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
    14:15:09,848 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final
    14:15:09,877 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    14:15:10,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 6.0)
    14:15:10,514 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: pokemax.war
    14:15:10,554 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.3.2 (Final)
    14:15:10,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = pokemax.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_6_0
    14:15:10,613 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment pokemax.war
    14:15:10,922 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'pokemax.war#pokemax'
    14:15:11,235 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    14:15:11,297 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Envers integration enabled? : true
    14:15:12,082 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
    14:15:12,091 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Hibernate: 
    14:15:12,092 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)     drop table if exists tb_habilidade
    14:15:12,093 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Hibernate: 
    14:15:12,094 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)     drop table if exists tb_pokemon
    14:15:12,095 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Hibernate: 
    14:15:12,095 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)     create table tb_habilidade (
    14:15:12,095 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         id bigint not null auto_increment,
    14:15:12,096 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         descricao varchar(150) not null,
    14:15:12,096 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         efeito_secundario varchar(255),
    14:15:12,096 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         nome varchar(20) not null,
    14:15:12,097 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         primary key (id)
    14:15:12,097 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)     ) ENGINE=InnoDB
    14:15:12,108 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Hibernate: 
    14:15:12,108 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)     create table tb_pokemon (
    14:15:12,108 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         id bigint not null auto_increment,
    14:15:12,108 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         ataque bigint not null,
    14:15:12,109 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         ataque_especial bigint not null,
    14:15:12,109 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         defesa bigint not null,
    14:15:12,109 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         defesa_especial bigint not null,
    14:15:12,109 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         descricao varchar(150) not null,
    14:15:12,109 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         hp bigint not null,
    14:15:12,110 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         nome varchar(20) not null,
    14:15:12,110 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         numeroDex bigint not null,
    14:15:12,110 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         tipoDois varchar(20),
    14:15:12,110 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         tipoUm varchar(20) not null,
    14:15:12,110 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         velocidade bigint not null,
    14:15:12,111 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         primary key (id)
    14:15:12,111 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)     ) ENGINE=InnoDB
    14:15:12,113 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Hibernate: 
    14:15:12,113 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)     alter table tb_pokemon 
    14:15:12,114 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)         add constraint UKa1g6imng0eltmqxv6v110t0go unique (nome, numeroDex)
    14:15:12,115 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HHH000230: Schema export complete
    14:15:13,520 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2 20150729-1131 para o contexto '/pokemax'
    14:15:15,948 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Running on PrimeFaces 5.3
    14:15:15,980 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /pokemax
    14:15:16,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "pokemax.war" (runtime-name : "pokemax.war")
    14:15:16,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    14:15:16,273 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    14:15:16,273 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 16424ms - Started 368 of 657 services (382 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

O meu arquivo persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="pokemax" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/pokemax" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="pokemax" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pokemax2" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

E minha classe Util:

```
package br.com.pokemax.util;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class HibernateUtil {

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }

}
```

Eu inclusive coloquei uma senha errada para ver se está abrindo conexão mas pelo visto não porque não vejo nenhum erro referente.

Alguém pode ajudar a resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repare que no seu arquivo `persistence.xml` tem a linha:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

Com o valor `create-drop` o hibernate vai apagar todas as tabelas, criar tabelas novas e no fim da sessão apagar todas as tabelas de novo. Mude para `create` ou `update`, que as tabelas continuaram no banco de dados mesmo depois da aplicação terminar.

Por exemplo:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

Com o valor `create` o hibernate vai apagar todas as tabelas no início e criar tabelas novas, apagando todos os seus dados que estavam no banco antes da aplicação começar. Se você quiser que os dados não sejam apagados use `update`.

Talvez seja isso, se não for comente aqui na resposta por favor!